# Taking off the reference number from in text cite

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I have a question about how to take off the reference number from in text cite? to explain more, I am using a thesis template, which uses the bibtex. This is how I cite a reference in text:

```
\citep[Rost and Riebesell, 2004]{rost2004coccolithophores}
```

the previous line produce a number before the Author names as follow:
    ....(1, Rost and Riebesell, 2004)
and when I use additional square brackets the number appears to the right of the names:

```
\citep[Rost and Riebesell, 2004][]{rost2004coccolithophores}
```

the cite will appear as follow:

```
....(Rost and Riebesell, 2004 1)
```

I want to take off this number from the in text cite to be like this:

```
....(Rost and Riebesell, 2004)
```

So I hope someone will guide me to the right way to do this?

here is the reference that I included in a file "thesis.bib":

```
@article{rost2004coccolithophores,
title={Coccolithophores and the biological pump: responses to environmental changes},
author={Rost, Bj{\"o}rn and Riebesell, Ulf},
booktitle={Coccolithophores},
pages={99--125},
year={2004},
publisher={Springer}
}
```

and I used the same package of \usepackage{natbib}, \bibliographystyle{apalike} and \bibliography{thesis}, but when I run the file I got this message:

> Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You should provide a small, working example people can copy-paste-compile. However, you are misusing the software ;). BibTeX should be writing 'Rost and R..., 2004` - not you. `\citep{rost2004whatever}` should be sufficient. You just need to choose an appropriate bibliography style i.e. one that uses author-year citations rather than numerical labels. `\bibliographystyle{}` is the key command here. You need to change the value to correspond to the format you need.

Comment: this style am using \bibliographystyle{apalike}, but still not getting what am looking for!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: If you want to stick to BibTeX, you should probably look at `natbib`. Otherwise, `biblatex` and `biber` are good.

Comment: Have you tried deleting all auxilliary files and recompiling from scratch (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more)?Incidentally, you shouldn't use the `@article` entry type for items that clearly aren't published in journals. Try using the type `@incollection` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the nature of the bibliographic entry in question, I suggest changing its type from `@article` to `@incollection`. One shouldn't use the `@article` entry type for pieces that weren't published in journals. I would also insert fields called `editor` and `address` and augment the `booktitle` field.

With these modifications in place, and with the `natbib` package loaded and the bibliography style set to `apalike`, the following output is generated by `\citep{rost2004coccolithophores}`. If you encounter any errors, try deleting all aux files and recompiling from scratch (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{thesis.bib}
@incollection{rost2004coccolithophores,
  author = "Bj{\"o}rn Rost and Ulf Riebesell",
  title  = "Coccolithophores and the biological pump: responses to environmental changes",
  pages  = "99-125",
  editor = "Hans A. Thierstein and Jeremy R. Young",
  booktitle = "Coccolithophores: From Molecular Processes to Global Impact",
  publisher = "Springer",
  address   = "Berlin",
  year   = 2004,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\citep{rost2004coccolithophores}
\bibliography{thesis}
\end{document}
```